# Location services(iPhone) other than Google

Tags: iphone, google-maps, sdk

In our iPhone application we have a requirement to display UK County and Area name of a location ( we have latitude and longitude) . Initially we used MAPKit framework (reverse geocoding) to get this information. But during testing we found that we are not getting correct data from Google always.

Can somebody suggest any alternative method to get this information ? We are ready to use paid services also.

Comment: You're not going to get correct data from *anyone* **always**.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/). They have pretty decent solutions for anything map service related. They use source from OpenStreetMap but you can do all sorts of customization to the maps. Another option is through Bing maps. It looks neat but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I tried CloudMade it is returning wrong data. It says "England" is county for a location. There is no County named "England" in UK. So i can't use CloudMade service.